# Additional info request on DSC Syntax for Binary Registry Key

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, dsc

I have more questions about implementing the solution found in: [DSC Syntax for Binary Registry Key](https://serverfault.com/questions/865450/dsc-syntax-for-binary-registry-key/865981#865981?newreg=00305196b58e4da3bfd4c6a60f455fba)

For the most part the solution suggested by Matthew Whetmore worked... but if the data starts with "00", somehow it is getting dropped. For e.g. for this data:

```
$reg = "00,01,04,80,64,00,00,00,70,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,
  14,00,00,00,02,00,50,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,
  00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,
  00,05,20,00,00,00,25,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,
  05,20,00,00,00,27,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,
  00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00"
```

The first set of 00 gets dropped when DSC adds it to the Registry, and the value in the registry starts with "01 04 ...". Looks like a whole left shift going on. The number of bytes stored in the registry is one less the original.

Any one else seeing this anomaly, and possible a fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what PowerShell lines you have used to save this data as a variable and write it to the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Given your starting string:

```
$reg = "00,01,04,80,64,00,00,00,70,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,
  14,00,00,00,02,00,50,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,
  00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,
  00,05,20,00,00,00,25,02,00,00,00,00,18,00,03,00,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,
  05,20,00,00,00,27,02,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,
  00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00"
```

The next step is to format the string by *basically* removing the spaces and commas:

```
$val = [String]::Join("",$reg.Split(",").Trim())
```

Then, **$val** is the variable that you'll want to write to the registry.